# Sending 20-byte characteristic values with CurieBLE

Tags: arduino, intel, bluetooth-lowenergy

The documentation for [Arduino/Genuino 101](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoard101)'s [CurieBLE library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/CurieBLE) states the following, in the section "Service Design Patterns":

> A characteristic value can be up to 20 bytes long. This is a key
> constraint in designing services. [...] You could also combine readings into a single characteristic, when a given sensor or actuator has multiple values associated with it.
>
> [e.g. Accelerometer X, Y, Z   => `200,133,150`]
>
> This is more efficient, but you need to be careful not to exceed the 20-byte limit. The accelerometer characteristic above, for example, takes 11 bytes as a ASCII-encoded string.

However, the typed [Characteristic constructors](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/BLECharacteristicConstructor) available in the API are limited to the following:

> - BLEBoolCharacteristic
> - BLECharCharacteristic
> - BLEUnsignedCharCharacteristic
> - BLEShortCharacteristic
> - BLEUnsignedShortCharacteristic
> - BLEIntCharacteristic
> - BLEUnsignedIntCharacteristic
> - BLELongCharacteristic
> - BLEUnsignedLongCharacteristic
> - BLEFloatCharacteristic
> - BLEDoubleCharacteristic

None of these types of Characteristics appear to be able to hold a 20-byte string. (I have tried the `BLECharCharacteristic`, and it appears to pertain to a single `char`, not a `char` array.)

Using CurieBLE, how does one go about using a string as a characteristic value, as described in the documentation as an efficient practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours issue described here in [official arduino 101 example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Genuino101CurieBLEHeartRateMonitor). Few strings of code how to set an array:

```
BLECharacteristic heartRateChar("2A37",  // standard 16-bit characteristic UUID
    BLERead | BLENotify, 2);
...
const unsigned char heartRateCharArray[2] = { 0, (char)heartRate };
heartRateChar.setValue(heartRateCharArray, 2);
```

As you can see characteristic's value set using "setValue" function with desired array as an argument. You can pass a String as char* pointing to an array.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I had tried using `BLECharacteristic`, but I had omitted to pass the final parameter - `maxLen`. It is interesting that the "Parameters" section in the [relevant documentation page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/BLECharacteristicConstructor) does not explain the `maxLen` parameter. It also appears that the typed constructors don't accept it - I get an error when I try to pass a third parameter to `BLECharCharacteristic`, although the documentation explicitly says its signature is `BLECharCharacteristic yourCharacteristicName(UUID, properties, maxLen)`.

Comment: For me it works and i see constructor taking 3 arguments (and it compiles). My setup is Arduino 1.6.7 + latest Visual Micro IDE. Also i just installed latest Intel Curie Boards 1.0.5 package.

Comment: Yes, the code in your answer works. It is the *typed* characteristics that do not appear to take 3 arguments, contrary to the documentation. I get an error at compile time saying `no matching function` when I try, for example, `BLECharCharacteristic someName("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", BLENotify, 5)`.

Comment: Why not use BLECharacteristic class? Value is defined as unsigned char* and seems this is suitable for you

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I ended up doing, I just described some experiments I did before I accomplished my goal, and how I discovered inconsistencies between the documentation and the implementation =)